# Bridge network connections

Tags: raspbian, networking

I install the Raspbian on my pi. and now I want to perform this :
https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections

But I cant seem to install the bridge utils.
Once I open the terminal, I type the first command and it doesnt show anything. 
Also how to edit the etc/network/interfaces file, it says the file isnt avaialble.
please help!

Comment: could you include some detail on the specific error messages?

Comment: yes this is done, now please tellme how to configure the bridge between the pc and the pi.. and then check if it is working.. teh connections as well as the commands..

Comment: Are you using Wifi or Ethernet? Bridging over Wifi may not work as desired/expected. I've had some trouble with it in the past (but *not* specifically with a Raspberry). You may want to try it with an ethernet connection to see if you can get a good baseline. Also, I seem to recall *bridge utils* may not be a package anymore (as stated in the old tutorials). I think i needed to install the missing pieces more traditionally, like `sudo apt-get install brctl`. Or I had to go looking for the new package names with `apt-file search` and `dpkg -S`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be root in order to bridge connections. If you look at your tutorial, there is a `#` at the beginning of every command they give, which indicates the commands are being enetered as the root user (regular users have a `$` instead). Try prepending your commands with `sudo` (you may need to enter your password), or switch to the root user by using `su`, if that has been enabled on your Pi.
Similarly, you need root priviledge to edit `/etc/network/interfaces`. Try `sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: ya all thsi done.. now please tellme how do i put that bridge in between teh pc and pi.. and then check if it si woeking.. the connections as well as teh commands..

Comment: @sakshi - I think two of the tests for the bridge are `brctl show` and `iptables -L  FORWARD` to see if traffic is being routed through it.