# Share USB modem internet via hotspot to devices

Tags: raspbian, internet, hotspot, modem

I have Quectel LTE USB Modem connected to Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ and able to access internet from modem.
Now, ifconfig has wwan0 connection with IP.
I want to start hotspot on Pi and share the internet to devices connected to hotspot.
Any guide/resources available?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **systemd-networkd** to create an access point and connect devices on it to the internet. In addition you can also do it with devices (maybe your laptop?) connected to the wired port **eth0**. How to create this "complete" solution you can look at [How can I set my pi 3 up to be WiFi AND ethernet router simultaneously?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/99598/79866).

The example there uses the interface name **usb0** instead of your **wwan0** but from the networking view there is no difference. Just replace *usb0* with *wwan0* and it should do.